# Directions are not displayed properly in Google My Places

Tags: google-maps

Here is my map with locations and directions: https://www.google.com/maps/ms?msid=201849003619318758787.0004e08ac8bd088dfd44d&msa=0&ll=39.249271,-116.257324&spn=14.382449,20.302734&dg=feature

Expected result: there should be routes visible between all of the locations.
It can be easily seen that some direction routes are not displayed.
Is it possible to fix this? I saved all the routes exactly the same way, so I don't understand why it looks like this.

I'm aware that if too many points are saved, only those on the first page will be displayed.
But even those on the first page are partially missing. See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of missing paths]

Comment: is this still an issue? If I recall, Google Maps removed the maximum 10 hops limit only recently. (I may also be misremembering and the limit is still there.)

Comment: @ale I don't know, I haven't used this since the date I opened this issue. Will check in the following weeks when I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Too many pins just click to next then back and then next

Img:

[image]

Quick fix - Dowoload geographic data KML file and start it in maps program eg. ("Marble Virtual Globe")

[image]

Comment: Please see my edit, all the paths up to Joshua Tree should be visible.